# want to change wordpress password format sysytem

Tags: php

Currently wordpress password format is in md5 hash with salt but i want to save password in only md5. We tried to remove hash and salt from the config but it gives error

original

```
function wp_hash($data, $scheme = 'auth') {
    $salt = wp_salt($scheme)
return hash_hmac('md5', $data, $salt);
```

We are trying

```
function wp_hash($data, $scheme = 'auth') {
//$salt = wp_salt($scheme);

return hash_hmac('md5', $data );}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use md5 for password hashes: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash
Is there any specific reason why you want to remove the salt? It is a security feature and if you have to use md5 for some reason, you should at least use it with salt.